# How to save URL to a Django ImageField

Tags: python-3.x, django, imagefield

I have Django model with Image field, but sometimes I don't need to actually upload file and store path to it, but I need to store only path. Especially url. I mean, I have web client, that receives both foreign urls like sun1-17.userapi.com and url of my own server, so sometimes I don't need to download but need to store url. Is it possible, to store url in ImageField, or I need to make CharField and save files via python? If its impossible, how do I save file in python3, having one, sent me via multipart?

Answer (score 1):

The URL field in the ImageField is ReadOnly, so you cannot write it. You should probably use in addition a URLField (better than a CharField) to save the URLs.
You can allow null values on both and use only the appropriate one according to your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
class FilePathField(path='', match=None, recursive=False, > allow_files=True, allow_folders=False, max_length=100, **options)
```

A `CharField` whose choices are limited to the filenames in a certain directory on the filesystem.

Has some special arguments, of which the first is required:

> `FilePathField.path`
>
> Required. The absolute filesystem path to a directory from which this `FilePathField` should get its choices. Example: "/home/images".

For more info visit the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FilePathField